# Statistical independence of least square estimator and residual in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, self-study, linear-model

I'm currently self studying linear regression. Following is an entrance exam problem of a graduate school.
 Consider the regression model with usual assumptions of the errors $y=X\beta+\epsilon$. Show that $\hat{β}$ and $e$ are statistically independent. $\hat{β}$ is the least square estimator and $e$ is the residual.) Honestly I don't even heard about independence of two random vectors. (I searched my text book of mathematical statistics and linear regression but I couldn't.) So how should I approach it? Thanks in advance.
Source of the problem is graduate entrance exam of Seoul National University of 2014

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Is $\epsilon$ multivariate normal?  What about $\hat{\beta}$?  What do you know about independence of components of a multivariate normal random vector and the covariance matrix?  Can you compute the covariance between $e$ and $\hat{\beta}$?  Can you at least get $\hat{\beta}$ and $e$ into the same equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Two Random vectors $\textbf{x},\textbf{y}$ are independant iff 
   $\forall i,j \in 1...n$,  $\textbf{x}_{i}$ and $\textbf{y}_{j}$ are independant.
2. Cross covariance matrix is defined by $cov(x,y )= E[(\textbf{x} - \mu_{\textbf{x}})(\textbf{y} - \mu_{\textbf{y}})^{T}]$
3. two multivariate normal random vectors are independent iff their cross covariance matrix is zero matrix. (Since each component of Cross covariance matrix is covariance of .. and two normal random variable's covariance=0 iff they are independant)
4. under the assumption that distribution of $\epsilon$ is $N(0,\sigma I)$ and 
   $\widehat{\beta}$ is the ordinary least square esitimator $Hy$, if one compute    covariance matrix of $\widehat{\beta}$ and $\textbf{e}$ , it is zero.
   Therefore they are statistically independant.
5. Am I right?
   thank you Brian Borchers, your commment was very helpful.

Comment: Not sure if zero covariance implies independence in this setting. Zero covariance certainly does not imply independence in general; is there something special in this setting?